# Python regex findall list index out of range

Tags: python, regex, data-manipulation

```
import re
with open("day2.txt", "r") as file: 
    line=file.read().split("\n")
    forward=0
    pos=0
    for i in range(0,len(line)-1):
        a=line[i]
        print(a)
        if (re.findall('^f',a)[0]) == 'f':
             forward=forward+int(((re.findall('\d',a)[0])))
        if (re.findall('^u',a)[0]) == 'u':
             pos=pos-int(((re.findall('\d',a)[0])))
        if (re.findall('^d',a)[0]) == 'd':
             pos=pos+int(((re.findall('\d',a)[0])))
print(forward*pos)
```

Here a or line[i] is a string. Test cases in the input.txt file is this but a few thousand lines of these

```
forward 6
up 4
forward 8
down 6
forward 9
```

Ideally the output should be the sum of `6+8`
I get an error when i run it as a script i get **list index out of range**, but no errors when i run it via the shell line by line

The exact error message is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "day2.py", line 10, in <module>
    if (re.findall('^u',a)[0]) == 'u':
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: What does `input.txt` look like?

Comment: It's a text file containing a few thousand lines, of text with a pattern similar to the code box under testcases. Ie ```forward 6\n
up 4\n
forward 8\n```, made the edit to the question mentioning the same. Thanks

Comment: Ok, can you add a few lines to your question, and make sure they include lines that cause your problem.

Comment: Updated it now, my bad

Comment: The issue is that your `re.findall('^f',a)` finds nothing, so the index 0 is out of range.  Do you really need to use `regex` here?  Is your file only `forward` and `up` followed by a number?

Comment: Yes the file is just forward up down and followed by a number each, i figured regex would be a faster way to isolate the digit and if it should be added or subtracted. Ive added the full code in an edit for clarity. The first condition does find the forward, the issue comes at the 2nd condition for "u"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to do with `regex`, but in my opinion that would be very over-engineered.  Since your file is made of a small number of known strings followed by a number, you can simply isolate the numbers based on the strings.

This should work:

```py
forward = 0
pos = 0
with open("input.txt", 'r') as file:
    elements = file.read().split("\n")

for e in elements:
    if "forward" in e:
        forward += int(e[7:])
    elif "up" in e:
        pos -= int(e[2:])
    elif "down" in e:
        pos += int(e[4:])

print(forward*pos)
```

Comment: Replace the string splicing index with -1 and you will always access the last value of a string. This removes the need to know the length of the string to start the slice at the correct index.  The strength of regex lies in in being able to define a pattern of unknown characters and pull whatever matches that pattern. If you know you are looking for a string 'forward' then using the **in** keyword is more readable and reduces code complexity. You can access all the elements in a list with **in** as well, accessing elements in a list by the index can cause errors and reduce readability.

Comment: I accept the solution, it worked. Thanks. But is there a way i can move forward with the over-engineered regex method.

Comment: @CrunchyLentils I didn't suggest `[-1]` because that would break for values greater than 9, but of course if the value is in the range [0, 9] that would be easier.